# Automatically fill in custom customer attribute based on name when customer registers

Tags: attributes, customer, register

I have a custom customer attribute called 'nickname' in my magento store.

When a new customer registers i want to be able to automatically fill this in based on their combined first and lastname. So if a customer registers as `John Doe` the nickname attribute will automatically be filled in as `johndoe`

I know in PHP i can turn `John Doe` into `johndoe` by doing:

```
$name = 'John Doe';
$nickname = str_replace(' ', '', $name);
$nickname = strtolower($nickname);
```

I just need to know how I can set this at the time of registering? What existing file/files would I have change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create an observer that listens to the event `customer_register_success`. This event is fired only on successful frontend registration, note that this would then not work if creating the account via the admin section.

The event gets passed the customer object so you can then get the last name and first name, combine them and set it against the customer.

```
$customer = $observer->getCustomer();
$customer->setNickname(strtolower($customer->getFirstName() . $customer->getLastName()));
$customer->save();
```

You could also do this on the `customer_save_before` event and check if their is an id set. If there is not one set then the customer is new. You can then set your `nickname` attribute value.

The advantages of the second event is you do not need to save the customer again as it happens before the first save so you are only editing the data being saved and it will work on creating customers in the admin section.